# MySQL: Difference between "Group Replication" and "Multi-master replication"

Tags: mysql, replication

Is there no difference?

I'm now trying to decide which method to use on my project.

I'm bit confused...

Comment: Looks like *Multi-primary replication* is a special case of *group replication*